# Character only jumps once on platform: AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

When my character drops onto the platform, I can move around and everything, and everything functions normally. The only problem is when I jump, it only allows it to jump one time, then after that doesn't respond to any upKey events.

I would like to know how to fix this problem I have with my code. I would like my character to be able to jump everytime I press the up arrow.

Heres my code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class GameCode extends MovieClip {

    var upKey:Boolean;
    var leftKey:Boolean;
    var rightKey:Boolean;
    var jump:Boolean = false;

    var xvelocity:int = 10;
    var yvelocity:int = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 1;
    var jumpspeed:int = -10;
    var onPlatform:Boolean;

    var startPosY:int;
    var startPosX:int;
    var lastPosY:int;
    var lastPosX:int;

    public function GameCode() {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function startGame(){
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyUp);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    function update(evt:Event){
        moveCharacter();
        yvelocity += gravity;

        if (!platform.hitTestObject(player)){
                player.y += yvelocity;
                onPlatform = false;
        }

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true)){
                yvelocity = 0;
                player.y = platform.y - 1;
                onPlatform = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function moveCharacter(){
        lastPosY = player.y;
        lastPosX = player.x;

        if (leftKey == true){
            player.x -= xvelocity;
        }
        if (rightKey == true){
            player.x += xvelocity;
        }
        if (upKey == true && onPlatform == true){
            yvelocity = jumpspeed;
            player.y += yvelocity;
        }
    }

    function checkKeyDown(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = true;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = true;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            upKey = true;
        }
    }

    function checkKeyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = false;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = false;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            upKey = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code with some traces. When you jump and land, `onPlatform` continues to resolve to false. This is because, when you loop through 10 iterations of `i`, you don't use `i` in the loop at all. By positioning the player 1 pixel above the platform and because you only ever check the player's exact coordinates for collision, that loop will never detect a hit. Change...

```
if (platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true)){
```

to...

```
if (platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y + i, true)){
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the etiquette is - I'm basically just trying to let the OP know I figured out his question. I figure another answer might register on his activity 'feed'. So...

When you jump and land, onPlatform continues to resolve to false. This is because, when you loop through 10 iterations of 'i', you don't use 'i' in the loop at all. By positioning the player 1 pixel above the platform and because you only ever check the player's exact coordinates for collision, that loop will never detect a hit. Change...

```
if (platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true)){
```

to...

```
if (platform.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y + i, true)){
```

...and it works.

Comment: Note: It is not necessary to copy and paste another answer to improve visibility. An upvote will do just fine.